# Does monit restart service if service was told to stop via systemd?

Tags: monitoring, monit

I am new to monit and don't use it up to now.

## Scenario

- monit should restart PostgresSQL if it is dead
- PostgresSQL gets started via systemd
- A sysadmin shuts down PostgresSQL via systemd since he wants to do special maintenance.
- Does monit start PostgresSQL, or does monit detect that it should be stopped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monit will apply logic set, so if you tell monit to start PostgresSQL if down, monit will try to start it up, indefirently from stop method (legit, crash etc..)

During maintenance, it is best to **unmonitor** the related service in monit and when maintenance is done, **monitor** it again

command is *monitor unmonitor* 
same for *monitor*

You could also use the web interface.